# why leanback DetailsDescriptionPresenter don't show all the content?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, leanback

Im working with the leanback library of android, I started with the template of android TV to try to catch how it works.

in the section of the Details description presenter where it show the description of the body I'm having this problem

Im trying to fill the viewHolder body but it don't show all the content, it crops to fit in the screen when is not full size, then when I key down to show it in full screen don't change to show all the content

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46nL3.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OJHi.jpg)

```
class DetailsDescriptionPresenter : AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter() {

    override fun onBindDescription(
            viewHolder: ViewHolder,
            item: Any
    ) {

        val movie = item as Movie

        viewHolder.title.text = movie.nombre
        viewHolder.subtitle.text = movie.studio

        var miHtml = "<h2>" +
                    movie.description.toString() +
                "</h2>" +
                "<br/>\n" +
                "<p style=\"margin-top:20px;\">" +
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu nisl non quam semper dignissim. Nulla tincidunt placerat aliquam. Sed nec lectus sit amet sapien scelerisque dignissim in sit amet enim.\n" +
                "\n" +
                "Sed mollis placerat ante, eu rutrum dui dignissim a. Phasellus dui ante, condimentum quis tincidunt at, scelerisque placerat diam.\n" +
                "\n" +
                "Duis a euismod orci, sed rhoncus orci. Pellentesque pulvinar ante non pulvinar mollis. In tempor erat in nisl ultrices, sodales posuere ipsum vestibulum. Donec finibus lacus a orci iaculis dignissim. Phasellus vel dui quam. Etiam ac risus finibus, mollis urna in, scelerisque orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas dapibus risus vel mauris viverra, ut elementum magna rutrum."+
                "</p>"

        viewHolder.body.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
            miHtml,
            HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
        )
    }
}
```

in the class VideoDetailsFragment the function that calls that im trying this:

```
class VideoDetailsFragment : DetailsFragment() {
   private fun setupDetailsOverviewRowPresenter() {
        // Set detail background.
        val detailsPresenter = FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter(DetailsDescriptionPresenter())
        detailsPresenter.backgroundColor =
                ContextCompat.getColor(activity,
                    R.color.cardview_dark_background
                )

        // Hook up transition element.
        val sharedElementHelper = FullWidthDetailsOverviewSharedElementHelper()
        sharedElementHelper.setSharedElementEnterTransition(activity, DetailsActivity.SHARED_ELEMENT_NAME)
        detailsPresenter.setListener(sharedElementHelper)
        detailsPresenter.isParticipatingEntranceTransition = true

        detailsPresenter.onActionClickedListener = OnActionClickedListener { action ->

            if (action.id === ACTION_BUY) {
                val row = DetailsOverviewRow(mSelectedMovie)
                mAdapter.add(row)
                val newItem = mSelectedMovie
                newItem!!.description = "NUEVO ROLLO"
                row.item = newItem
                mPresenterSelector.addClassPresenter(DetailsOverviewRow::class.java, detailsPresenter)

            }

        }
        mPresenterSelector.addClassPresenter(DetailsOverviewRow::class.java, detailsPresenter)
        println(mPresenterSelector)
    }
}
```